# vue3 composition api adds or removes classes for custom input boxes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const { modelValue = '' } = defineProps<{
  modelValue: string
}>()
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const isFilled = ref(false)

const value = computed({
  get() {
    return modelValue
  },
  set(value: string) {
    isFilled.value = value.length > 0
    emit('update:modelValue', value)
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="value" :class="{ 'filled': isFilled }" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
```

[sfc playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

This will not take effect when the key is pressed for the first time.
For example: press abcdefg, the last input box displays bcdefg, delete it with the backspace key and try again, it is still the same.

I commented out `isFilled.value = value.length > 0` and it works fine, but otherwise, how can I add a class to the element?

The effect I need is to add a class named filled to it when the value of the input box is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have used a watcher for this task, example code:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const { modelValue = '' } = defineProps<{
  modelValue: string
}>()
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const isFilled = ref(false)
const inputText = ref("")

watch(inputText,(newValue, oldValue)=>{
  isFilled.value = inputText.value.length > 0
  emit('update:modelValue', inputText.value)
})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="inputText" :class="{ 'filled': isFilled }" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
```

If you just want to add the class you can do that inline aswell.
example:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
const inputText = ref("")
</script>
<template>
  <input v-model="inputText" :class="{ 'filled': (inputText.length>0) }" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I chose the second option you provided. Before, I thought that I needed to reimplement two-way binding to make the component use v-model. After reading your answer, I realized that I don't need to do this.